# How to create a path using add_path in NetworkX?

Tags: python, path, networkx, edges

I created an edge using the function g.add_edge(node1, node2) for every parcel in my parcel list (parcel1, parcel2, parcel3)  and I would like to create a path using these added edges and store this path for each parcel. I tried using add_path but when I print the path, I get `None`.

This is the code:

```
#To add an expensive edge for each parcel:
for p, plrow in parcellist.iterrows():
    g.add_edge(plrow[0], plrow[8], Node1_reference= plrow[0], Node2_reference= plrow[8], OriginT= plrow[2], OriginX= plrow[3] , Cost = 10000, Capacity= 10000)
    print(plrow[0], plrow[8])
    print("path", nx.add_path(g, [plrow[0], plrow[8]]))
```

This is the output:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

documentation of [nx.add_path](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/generated/networkx.classes.function.add_path.html):

> ```
> add_path(G_to_add_to, nodes_for_path, **attr)[source]
> Add a path to the Graph G_to_add_to.
> ```

The path is added to the graph, and the function returns None.

I think a better function for your use case would be `shortest_path`:

```
# dummy graph and parcels
G = nx.from_numpy_array(np.random.rand(10,10)>.5)
dummy_parcels = [np.random.choice(G.nodes, size=2)]


for source, target in dummy_parcels:
    print('path', nx.shortest_path(G, source, target))
```